# How to test the arguments passed to a function of ScalarDB

Tags: scala, mockito, scalardb

I am using `ScalarDB`. It provides ACID capabilities over `Cassandra`. - https://scalar-labs.github.io/scalardb/javadoc/

`ScalarDB` is `Java` based and I am using it in `Scala` code

The way to insert a value in `Cassandra` using `Scalardb` is to call `Put` method. Eg.

```
def add() = {
    val putAnswer: Put = new Put(pAnswerKey)
      .forNamespace(keyspaceName)
      .forTable(tablename)
      .withCondition(mutationCondition)
      .withValue(new TextValue("answer_id", answer.answer_id.get.toString))
      .withValue(new TextValue("image", convertImageToString(imageData)))
      .withValue(new TextValue("answer", convertAnswersFromModelToString(answer.answer)))
      .withValue(new BigIntValue("creation_year", answer.creationYear.getOrElse(0)))
      .withValue(new BigIntValue("creation_month", answer.creationMonth.getOrElse(0)))
      .withValue(new TextValue("notes", answer.notes.getOrElse("")))
    
    logger.trace(s"putting answer ${putAnswer}")
    transaction.put(putAnswer)
....
}
```

I want to unit test the `add` method by capturing the argument passed to `put`. I am stuck at a point where I don't know how to get the `Value` passed to `put`. How do I type cast to required values?

repository.add(repoTestEnv.mockDistributedTransaction,repoTestEnv.answerTestEnv.answerOfAPracticeQuestion)
val argumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClassPut,Put

```
  verify(repoTestEnv.mockDistributedTransaction,times(1)).put(argumentCaptor.capture())
  val argumentsInvoked = argumentCaptor.getAllValues
  argumentsInvoked.size mustBe 1
  val argument = argumentsInvoked.get(0)
  val values = argument.getValues //this is util.Map[String,Value[_]]
  logger.trace(s"arguments were ${argument.getValues}") //this prints the following
```

`{answer_id=TextValue{name=answer_id, value=Optional[11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111]}, image=TextValue{name=image, value=Optional[{"image":["image1binarydata","image2binarydata"]}]}, answer=TextValue{name=answer, value=Optional[{"answer":[{"filename":"c.js","answer":"some answer"}]}]}, creation_year=BigIntValue{name=creation_year, value=2019}, creation_month=BigIntValue{name=creation_month, value=12}, notes=TextValue{name=notes, value=Optional[some notes]}}`

Problem - I don't know how to further pick each value and compare it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `Value` is an interface, I had to typecast it like follows.

```
val value = values.get("answer_id").asInstanceOf[TextValue]
      value.getString.isPresent mustBe true
      value.getString.get() mustBe "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create an expected Put and verify with Mockito?